# Replacing pieces of strings within a string between 4 " characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

​
In JavaScript, I have an automatically generated array of strings (through an GET request) that have the character " within a string. My aim is to remove all the text within two " in a single string.
Using the `replace()` function, works for the strings that only have 2 " within the string but not 4.

For strings that have 4 " (two pieces of text that need to be removed), `array[3]` in example below, the `replace()` function removes too much text. It removes all the text found between the first " and last ", while it should remove the text between the first & second " AND between the third & fourth ".

Would anybody know a solution for this?

Please note: The array which I use in my code is generated automatically from somewhere else. Changing the array of strings manually is not possible. For the script below and in the Fiddle I use escape character \ to include the " within the string, but in my actual array these are not present.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var array = ["John Mayer & Peter Right", "John \"the Man\" Mayer & Peter Right", "John Mayer & Peter \"the King\" Right", "John \"the Man\" Mayer & Peter \"the King\" Right"]
new_array = []
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var edit_string = array[i].replace(/".*"/, "")
        new_array.push(edit_string)
    }
console.log(new_array) // ["John Mayer & Peter Right", "John  Mayer & Peter Right", "John Mayer & Peter  Right", "John  Right"]
```

I have a working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jelle002/jgorq16j/3) that returns the wrong array of strings.

Comment: shortified: console.log(array.map(e=>e.replace(/".*"/,"")));

Comment: try adding lazy and global flag  `/".*?"/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not an regex expert. I would do this with plain js:

```
console.log(array.map(e=>e.split("\"").map((a,i)=>i%2==0?a:undefined).join("")));
```

Split with ", then remove every second part of the array.